# R commands for finding mode in R seem to be wrong

Tags: r

I watched video on YouTube re finding mode in R from list of numerics. When I enter commands they do not work. R does not even give an error message. The vector is

```
X <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Then instructor says use

```
temp <- table(as.vector(x))
```

to basically sort all unique values in list. R should give me from this command `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` but nothing happens except when the instructor does it this list is given. Then he says to use command,

```
names(temp)[temp--max(temp)]
```

which basically should give me this: 1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 where 3 shows that the mode is 2 because it is repeated 3 times in list. I would like to stay with these commands as far as is possible as the instructor explains them in detail. Am I doing a typo or something?

Comment: I don't this is a good way to learn R. You are typing from what you seen from video, but first line used `X`, second line used `x`. R is case sensitive. It's better to learn basics first instead of blindly following commands. Even if all these commands gave correct result, you still didn't learn much from it.

Comment: Also I don't see the point of `as.vector(X)` when `X` is a vector. Forget this video.

Comment: There are lots of nice resources and tutorials on [the R tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) which are probably a better starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of confused.

```
X <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)  ## define vector
temp <- table(as.vector(X))
```

> to basically sort all unique values in list.

That's not exactly what this command does (`sort(unique(X))` would give a sorted vector of the unique values; note that in R, *lists* and *vectors* are different kinds of objects, it's best not to use the words interchangeably).  What `table()` does is to *count* the number of instances of each unique value (in sorted order); also, `as.vector()` is redundant.

> R should give me from this command 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 but nothing happens except when the instructor does it this list is given.

If you assign results to a variable, R doesn't print anything.  If you want to see the value of a variable, type the variable's name by itself:

```
temp
```

you should see

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

the first row is the labels (unique values), the second is the counts.

> Then he says to use command, `names(temp)[temp--max(temp)]` which basically should give me this: 1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 where 3 shows that the mode is 2 because it is repeated 3 times in list.

No.  You already have the sequence of counts stored in `temp`. You should have typed

```
names(temp)[temp==max(temp)]
```

(note `=`, not `-`) which should print

```
[1] "2"
```

i.e., this is the mode.  The logic here is that `temp==max(temp)` gives you a logical vector (a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values) that's only `TRUE` for the elements of `temp` that are equal to the maximum value; `names(temp)[temp==max(temp)]` selects the elements of the names vector (the first row shown in the printout of `temp` above) that correspond to `TRUE` values ...

Comment: So many typos. I'm amazed that you can figure out `--` is actually `==`.

Comment: Thanks for your input dracodoc and alistaire. jay28

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks but I did as you suggested and please bear in mind I am new to R. x <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) then typed in under this, temp. I got an error message Error: object 'temp' not found. I get though what you wrote about names(temp)[temp==max(temp)]. Thanks again. jay28.